# Does form.onload exist in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to run some code onload of a form in WPF. Is it possible to do this? I am not able to find where to write code for form onload.

Judging by the responses below it seems like what I am asking is not something that is typically done in WPF? In Vb.Net winforms it is easy, you just go to the onload event and add the code that you need ran on load. For whatever reason, in C# WPF it seem very difficult or there is no standard way to do this. Can someone please tell me what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Would not you code work in the New() methid of the form?

Comment: [See Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742302.aspx)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You can subscribe to the Window's [Loaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx) event and do your work in the event handler:

```
public MyWindow()
{
  Loaded += MyWindow_Loaded;
}

private void MyWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  // do work here
}
```

Alternatively, depending on your scenario, you may be able to do your work in [OnInitialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.oninitialized.aspx) instead.  See the Loaded event docs for a discussion of the difference between the two.

Comment: Why do you subscribe to the event in the constructor instead of in the XAML?

Comment: Because this to me is logically part of the code -- the behaviour -- rather than the view (it's a workaround for the lack of a virtual OnLoaded method).  For example, if I had to give the XAML to a graphic designer for editing in Blend, I'd prefer them not to be able to modify the Loaded event handling.  It's a marginal call though!

Answer (score 36):

Use the Loaded event of the Window. You can configure this in the XAML like below:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Your App" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
```

Here is what the Window_Loaded event would look like:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This question was asked 4 years ago, but this answer may help others too so here goes -->
To do it simply and quickly - down and dirty, put the code you want to run in a method in the code-behind. then simply call the method before the `MainWindow() InitializeComponent()`. This poses dangers, but most times it works because the components are loaded before window initiation/display.
(This is working code from one of my projects.)
Let's say you want to play a short wave file when the app fires up. It would look like this;

```
using ...
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace yourNamespace_Name
{
    /// sumary >
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// /sumary>
    public partial class MainWindow : System.Windows.Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            /*call your pre-written method w/ all the code you  wish to
             * run on project load. It is wise to set the method access
             * modifier to 'private' so as to minimize security risks.*/
            playTada();

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void playTada()
        {
            var player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
            player.Stream = Properties.Resources.tada;
            // add the waveFile to resources, the easiest way is to copy the file to
            // the desktop, resize the IDE window so the file is visible, right 
            // click the Project in the solution explorer & select properties, click
            // the resources tab, & drag and drop the wave file into the resources 
            // window. Then just reference it in the method.
            // for example: "player.Stream = Properties.Resources.tada;"         
            player.Play();
            //add garbage collection before initialization of main window
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps those that are searching.   :-)

Answer (score -2):

`Loaded` event is raised after project is build. To do stuff before, you can ovveride `OnStartup` method in `App.xaml.cs`.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        //...
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```