# Show popup on first startup before firewall popup

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to have a popup show up the first time the application is opened, and only the first time. This popup will have instructions for the required firewall settings, so this needs to be displayed before the Windows Defender Firewall popup comes up. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Does a state help? If you check if before you try to open a socket it should work to my understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have any file, for example an [XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=netframework-4.8) file (which could also act as a config file if needed and can be created with hard coded defaults).
On startup, if the file does not exist, that means it's the first time the application is opened. So display the popup. When the user reads the instructions and clicks Ok, create the file and continue with the app. At this point, the network code will eventually trigger the windows firewall popup.
Alternatively you can use a [Windows Registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry?view=netframework-4.8) key.

Comment: Or really any type of file would do here. It could just be an empty text file if the OP's app does not need a config file.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a little more detail on how to implement this or find an example that would point me in the right direction? Do I check to see if the file exists, then create a popup, then create the file? Sorry, I’m very new to coding :)

Comment: There is sample code and links to more sample code within the links provided. If you have doubts I will explain how I would do it. I'd make a new landing form. on form loaded ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619348/does-form-onload-exist-in-wpf ) check if the file exists. If the file is found, load the main form of the app (this will happen automatically after the first time). If the file is not found, return and stay on this landing form where the user can read and press ok. When you press ok, on click, create the file and load the main form.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you so much for the extra guidance, it really helped.