# Program wont run, no errors, when calling async task

Tags: c#, aws-sdk-net

I'm new to C# programming, and am learning as I go.

I'm working on a program to test whether a computer can connect to specific servers and ports.

I got the program itself working fine, when the list of servers and ports were hard coded into it.

I worked on a separate project to connect to an AWS S3 bucket and get the list of server addresses from a file there and load them into a dictionary. That worked fine.

But when I try to move the function in that project to my main project, if I call it, the program wont load, but there is also no error in the console log.

Here is the source code, with the working functions removed temporarily.

What it should do is when ran, run the ReadObjectDataAsync, with the specified s3 object name, and dictionary name, so that it preloads the info into the 3 specified dictionaries.

If I comment out the 3 ReadObjectDataAsync lines, the program runs as expected. If I leave them in, the program builds, is shown in task manager, but the window never actually opens.
I know the ReadObjectDataAsync function works, as it works in its own project

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Amazon.S3.Model;
using Amazon.S3;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ConnectionChecker
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public static string PublicKey = "PUBKEYHERE";
        public static string SecretKey = "SECKEYHERE";
        public static Dictionary<string, string> stream_servers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        public static Dictionary<string, string> other_servers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        public static Dictionary<string, string> ports = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        public static AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(PublicKey, SecretKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ReadObjectDataAsync("streamservers.conf", stream_servers).Wait();
            ReadObjectDataAsync("ports.conf", ports).Wait();
            ReadObjectDataAsync("servers.conf", other_servers).Wait();

            if (stream_servers.Count > 0)
            {
                ProgramStatus.Text = "Loaded";
            }
        }


        public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //run through connection test and display results on form.
            
        }
    
    
        

        static async Task ReadObjectDataAsync(string itemname, Dictionary<string, string> listname)
        {
            string responseBody = "";
            try
            {
                GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
                {
                    BucketName = "bucketname",
                    Key = itemname
                };
                using (GetObjectResponse response = await s3Client.GetObjectAsync(request))
                using (Stream responseStream = response.ResponseStream)
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    responseBody = reader.ReadToEnd(); // Now you process the response body.
                    string[] result = responseBody.Split("\n\r".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                    //Console.WriteLine("Lines: " + result.Count());
                    foreach (string line in result)
                    {
                        string[] words = line.Split("::");
                        listname.Add(words[0], words[1]);
                    }
                    //Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
                }
            }
            catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
            {
                // If bucket or object does not exist
                Console.WriteLine("Error encountered ***. Message:'{0}' when reading object", e.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unknown encountered on server. Message:'{0}' when reading object", e.Message);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't `.Wait()`. You are deadlocking. Go async all the way.

Comment: It seems like that Wait() is blocking your UI which means that the tasks are still running. 
Try invoking `ReadObjectDataAsync` like this: `Task.Run(() => ReadObjectDataAsync("", obj));`. If your UI Windows now appears you know that your tasks are not finished and there is an issue within `ReadObjectDataSync`

Comment: And you cannot have async calls in a ctor. Use for example OnLoad event handler or something similar.

Comment: ... I mean of course the WPF counterpart to what in WinForms would be the OnLoad handler. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2619375/982149

Comment: And ideally, you would have a whole different class to hold your data and only bind your ui components to that viewmodel. WPF code behind should be as non-existent as can be.

Comment: Thanks all.
Max that worked perfectly.
Thanks for the suggestion Fildor
I'm still pretty new to C#, so am learning as I go. am working my way through a course, but it's kinda slow going and the projects in it are pretty boring lol